# Most efficient way to calculate affected rows with a limit

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column `result` in my table and want to know how many rows are affected where `result` contains a specific number like '3' in the last 25 rows before a specific `id`.

Eg: Want to know how many rows have a `result` = 3 of the 25 rows before the `id` "500".

What is the most efficiënt way to reach this in Php and MySQL.

Comment: What you mean of `before a specific id`?

Comment: Instead of using comments, add the code you are using, that works and that you want to optimize. At least we can understand what you are querying, as the question itself is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that completely with SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(x.result)
FROM (
   SELECT    *
   FROM      table
   WHERE     id < 500
   ORDER BY  id DESC
   LIMIT 25
) x
WHERE  x.result = 3
```

First you find all entries that are relevant to your query by specifying the search criteria. Then you limit this search to 25 items and sort it in reverse order. That should yield the 25 last elements. Finally you just do your `COUNT()` for items with a result value of 3.

Comment: This query will affect all rows before the given `id`

Comment: Want to know how many rows have a result = 3 of the 25 rows before the id "500"

Comment: It might be a good idea to provide an example for a question like this. Anyway...I changed my answer, see if that works better for you.

Comment: For the record: I'm looking for the most efficiënt solution. I already solved the puzzle.

Comment: For the record: You're not making any friends here. You waste our time with your weird games and lie about what your situation actually is. If you want people to help you, be honest. I'm done here. Good look with your "optimization".

Comment: @TillHelge Your first answer: "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `table` WHERE `result` = 3 AND `id` < 25 LIMIT 25" wasn't answering my question at all since I was looking for the most efficiënt way to solve this problem. I appreciate your help but my downvote was addressed to your first answer.

Comment: This has nothing to do with my first answer. The problem is that your question doesn't mention the code you already have to solve the problem. So instead of letting us help you optimize the code you have, you make us jump through hoops and downvote people trying to help you. That's just bad manners all around.

Comment: Fixed your query by replacing id <25 with id <500

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(result)
FROM   table
WHERE  id < '$specificID'
  AND  result = 3
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: This query will always return 25 because your selection contains only rows where the result contains a 3.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `your_table` 
WHERE result LIKE '%3%' 
AND id < 500
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 25;
```

Comment: This will always return 25 because you limit your rows on the result I want to know ;-)

Comment: Stop downvoting people just because you don't explain clearly. They're trying their best to help you out. Don't be so ungrateful

Comment: @YourCommonSense explain this

Comment: @ArekvanSchaijk : This is one `like '3' in the last 25 rows` totally different from this `result = 3 of the 25 rows` this.

Comment: @Ranjith Looks like you wasting your time helping and ending up downvoted. That's frustrating indeed!

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, something the length of this comment is fine, but it *is* needed.